# How to update: From a total value, Add and Subtract according to the pressed button within the allotted value

Tags: flutter, dart, logic

I'm looking for help on how to have the total number of points accumulated from Challenge 1 and Challenge 2 saved to a variable, as well as the remaining points. I feel like I'm close but not quite there. The _totalChallengeWager will not update with my existing code.

I'm attempting to build a game with a series of challenges that the users may allocate points to from the total points.

[image: screenshot of build]

For instance, there are 10 total points available and I may allocate those 10 points between 2 challenges. But I do not have to allocate all 10 points For instance:

- 5 to challenge 1, 5 to challenge 2 (I used all 10 points)
- 6 to challenge 1, 2 to challenge 2 (I used 8 points, have 2 remaining)
- etc.

I think I need at least 4 variables:

1. Store the value of points allocated in challenge 1. (int _firstChallengeWager)
2. Store the value of points allocated in challenge 2. (int _secondChallengeWager)
3. Store the total number of points allocated in challenge 1 + challenge 2. (int _totalChallengeWager)
4. Store the total available remaining points. (int _remainingTokens)

I think I need at least 3 functions:

1. Increase points per challenge while ensuring it stays within the points allocation. (void _challengeTokenIncrease())

```
  void _challengeTokenIncrease() {
    setState(() {
      _challengeTokenWager = _challengeTokenWager + _challengeTokenIncrement;
    });
    if (_challengeTokenWager >= 10) {
      //TODO: do not increase
    }
  }
```

2. Decrease points per challenge while ensuring it stays within the points allocation. (void _challengeTokenDecrease())

```
  void _challengeTokenDecrease() {
    setState(() {
      _challengeTokenWager = _challengeTokenWager - _challengeTokenIncrement;
    });
    if (_challengeTokenWager >= 0) {
      //TODO: do not decrease
    }
  }
```

3. Calculate the sum of points between challenge 1 + challenge 2. (void _totalChallengeWagerFn())

```
  void _totalChallengeWagerFn() {
    setState(() {
      _totalChallengeWager =
          _challengeTokenWager - (_firstChallengeWager + _secondChallengeWager);
    });
  }
```

Code for a ChallengeTile:

```
class ChallengeTile extends StatelessWidget {
  ChallengeTile({
    super.key,
    required this.challengeTitle,
    required this.contextBlock,
    required this.userDefinedValue,
    this.challengeIncrease,
    this.challengeDecrease,
  });

  String challengeTitle;
  String contextBlock;
  int userDefinedValue;
  VoidCallback? challengeIncrease;
  VoidCallback? challengeDecrease;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(challengeTitle),
              Text(contextBlock),
            ],
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: challengeDecrease,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
          Text(userDefinedValue.toString()),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: challengeIncrease,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And references within the view:

```
//ChallengeTile 1
ChallengeTile(
challengeTitle: 'Challenge 1',
contextBlock: 'with total challenge',
userDefinedValue: _totalChallengeWager,
challengeDecrease: _challengeTokenDecrease,
challengeIncrease: _challengeTokenIncrease,
),

//ChallengeTile 2
ChallengeTile(
challengeTitle: 'Challenge 2',
contextBlock: 'with challenge',
userDefinedValue: _challengeTokenWager,
challengeDecrease: _challengeTokenDecrease,
challengeIncrease: _challengeTokenIncrease,
),
```

Comment: What specifically are you looking for help with?

Comment: I'm looking for help on how to have the total number of points accumulated from Challenge 1 and Challenge 2 saved to a variable, as well as the remaining points. I feel like I'm close but not quite there. The _totalChallengeWager will not update with my existing code.

Comment: Do you want such output? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HJIB4iExuz4giS9KgEijpeY8yPtroeER/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to wrote this code based on the information you have provided, I hope it's right for you:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _firstChallengeWager = 0;
  int _secondChallengeWager = 0;
  int _totalChallengeWager = 10;

  void _challengeTokenIncrease(bool isChallengeOne) {
    if (_firstChallengeWager + _secondChallengeWager >= 10) return;
    if (isChallengeOne) {
      _firstChallengeWager += 1;
    } else {
      _secondChallengeWager += 1;
    }
    _totalChallengeWager -= 1;

    setState(() {});
  }

  void _challengeTokenDecrease(bool isChallengeOne) {
    if (isChallengeOne) {
      if (_firstChallengeWager == 0) return;
      _firstChallengeWager -= 1;
    } else {
      if (_secondChallengeWager == 0) return;
      _secondChallengeWager -= 1;
    }
    _totalChallengeWager += 1;

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Total: $_totalChallengeWager"),
            ChallengeTile(
              challengeTitle: "Challenge 1",
              contextBlock: 'with total challenge',
              userDefinedValue: _firstChallengeWager,
              challengeDecrease: () => _challengeTokenDecrease(true),
              challengeIncrease: () => _challengeTokenIncrease(true),
            ),
            ChallengeTile(
              challengeTitle: 'Challenge 2',
              contextBlock: 'with challenge',
              userDefinedValue: _secondChallengeWager,
              challengeDecrease: () => _challengeTokenDecrease(false),
              challengeIncrease: () => _challengeTokenIncrease(false),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**_totalChallengeWager** will store remaining token, it was shown on screen and is updated every time you tap the icon **+** or **-**

Comment: With the exclusion of needing to change `_totalChallengeWager` to `+=` for the increase and `-=` for the decrease, this works. Thank you!